# Вычисление цифры после точки

Tags: python, python-3.x

Какие есть варианты реализации вычисления цифры числа после `.`?

Например, для ввода `1.89` результат `8`.

Comment: Вы сами-то  вопрос понимаете?

Comment: Ванга-моде вкл: `input().split('.', 1)[-1][0]`

Comment: @andreymal, ванга из вас чудесная, несколько вопросов:  1)Какие косяки я допустил в вопросе? 2)При отсутствии дробной части у числа выхлоп = 1, как можно реализовать выхлоп дробной части как 0?

Comment: А, нет, при отсутствии дробной части он берет первое цифру числа

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так: http://ideone.com/SMFYJc

```
x = 1.89
print(int(x % 1 * 10))
```

Только не забываем про погрешность. Возможно, стоит что-нибудь (в зависимости от диапазона чисел) добавить, чтобы получать правильные результаты.

Если числа могут быть отрицательными, следует использовать `abs`: http://ideone.com/Zuzvb2

```
x = -1.89
print(int(abs(x) % 1 * 10))
```

Comment: Ваше решение неправильно работает для отрицательных чисел

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, да, надо добавить `abs`, если отрицательные тоже нужны: http://ideone.com/Zuzvb2

Comment: Да, это именно тот случай, но возник вопрос: как это работает? Таким образом, в случае с 1.89 он вычисляет остаток от деления на 1, получая 0.89 . после он умножает на 10, получая 8.9. Как при этом была отброшена девятка?

Comment: @biryulin04, вызовом `int`.

Answer (score 4):

Вместо велосипедов или волшебства (даже если они с первого взгляда кажутся вполне рабочими) есть стандартная для многих языков функция [modf](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.modf), которая разделяет число на целую и дробную части.

```
import math

print(math.modf(3.1415))
print(math.modf(-3.0009))
print(math.modf(7))

>>> (0.14150000000000018, 3.0)
>>> (-0.0009000000000001229, -3.0)
>>> (0.0, 7.0)
```

Что в дальнейшем делать с дробной частью, зависит уже от конкретной задачи. Если нужно *округлить* до 1 значимой цифры - [round](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round). Если получить только первую цифру - `int(f * 10)` - `print(int(0.14150000000000018 * 10))`

Независимо от выбранного метода получения дробной части, вас на этом пути может подстеречь ошибка округления, из-за которой вы можете получить не совсем ожидаемые результаты:

```
numb = 3.3
frac, integral = math.modf(numb)
print(frac)
print(frac * 10)
>>> 0.2999999999999998
>>> 2.9999999999999982
```

Одним из способов избавления от этого может стать модуль [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal):

```
from decimal import Decimal
numb = 3.3
decim = Decimal(str(numb))
print(decim - decim.to_integral_exact())
>>> 0.3
```

Еще можно округлить до нужной цифры:

```
numb = 3.3
frac, integral = math.modf(numb)
print(round(frac, 1))
>>> 0.3
```

Comment: Есть какая-то разница между `modf` и `%`, если целая часть не нужна?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял вопрос:

```
num = 1.89
mant = str(float(num))
mant = int(mant[mant.find('.')+1:])
print(mant) #print 89
```